# NFC Chipset evaluation tool

Tags: visual-c++, networking, nfc, chipset

I need to develope a NFC chipset evaluation tool. i need to connect the NFC board (that includes the NFC chip) to PC (running in Windows). then i need to get all the data of the chip to my PC using a software tool. this is the first time i am trying to do it. i need some advises regarding the first steps. i suppose, i would use a TCP-IP protocol to connect with the chipset. but how exactly it would work? for example, there is a USB-tester... http://www.vconsole.com/client/?page=page&id=13. my tool will be similar to this.
i also need to validate in the low level entry, for the framework.
i need to have a process description for the development of the tool. what are the steps?
thanks for your advices.

Comment: This is far too few information about the NFC board in question. What kind of NFC board are you using? What kind of connectivity does it support? Does it run some sort of operating system or does it have a Microcontroller that runs some sort of proprietary firmware?

Comment: it is Open NFC Microread chipset. it supports USB/I2C connectivity. it has a nfc controller that runs proprietary firmware...

Comment: the question is can i still use TCP/IP protocol to connect to the NFC board when it has a microcontroller that runs a firmware?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use TCP/IP over a USB/I2C connection. Most test boards come with software that you can use to connect to the board. What you are asking is a very broad question. If you are trying to write your own question, or hook it up to Excel to run tests with, you are progressing down a very time consuming path. People here are willing to help you figure out a question you are stuck on, but not to do all the hard work for you.

Like I said, you are starting on a BIG project, and will need to research A LOT. Then I'd recommend asking specific questions rather than very general questions.

As far as where to start, I'd start by writing down everything you want to know, and then start figuring out how to get each individual piece.